# Proof of inequality using Taylor series and geometric series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

I would like to prove that, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\log\bigg(1-\bigg (\frac{\overline{\theta}}{\theta}\bigg )^{n+1}\bigg) \leq \bigg | \frac{\overline{\theta}}{\theta-\overline{\theta}} \bigg |,$$

where $\theta = \frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4c}}{2}$  and $\overline{\theta}= \frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4c}}{2}$

The hint is to use the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and bound it from above with a geometric series.

My attempt so far: 
Let $x= \frac{\overline{\theta}}{\theta}$ and I know that $|x| < 1$, so using Wolfram alpha I found the Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$, which is,
\begin{equation}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(-x)^n}{n} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2n}(x)^n}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x)^n}{n}\end{equation}

The geometric series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

Now, my question is, can I do the following? 
$$\bigg|-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}\bigg| \leq \bigg|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\bigg| = \bigg |\frac{x}{1-x} \bigg |=\bigg | \frac{\overline{\theta}}{\theta-\overline{\theta}} \bigg |$$

Is it correct to do the above? If it's not correct do you have suggestions for a correct way?

Comment: What information do we have on the values (and signs) of $b,c$. Consequently, do we know something about $\bar{\theta}/\theta$ (is it always <1 in absolute value, what is its sign ...)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the reply, a and b are both positive integers such that $a|b$ so $b=ac$, and so c is also a positive integer.

Comment: You speak about an "a" to which we have not been introduced.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh yes, sorry. Well anyway b and c are positive constants. Is this enough to know?